# Windows XP clients strange message in event log

Tags: windows-xp, windows-event-log, com+

I am getting the following error message in the event log of many of my windows XP clients

The COM+ Event System failed to create an instance of the subscriber partition:{41E90F3E-56C1-4633-81C3-6E8BAC8BDD70}!new:{6295DF2D-35EE-11D1-8707-00C04FD93327}. CoGetObject returned HRESULT 8000401A.

Does anyone know what it means or how to cure it? Our network has been having a few issues recently with logon scripts not running and users not being able to access network shares could this error have something to do with it?

HRESULT 8000401A - I read somewhere that this result means unable to contact domain controller, is this right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this might be something to do with Synchronization Manager.

http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=4356&eventno=1035&source=EventSystem&phase=1